# How to pass JS Object to jQuery function .queue()

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I use OOP and jQuery in my developments. 
I used to passed my current object `this` to jQuery functions like this :

```
$(myElement).live('click', this, function(el){
  // I can access to my JS object using el.data
});
```

But I can't find how to do similar thing with jQuery function `.queue()`.
Is it possible ?

**EDIT**

I give you the context in which I want to use `.queue()` :

```
CAPTIVEA.widget.Message = {
    /**
     * Displays generated message on the screen
     * @method display
     * @public
     */
    display: function() {
        // Display Message
        $('.message')[this.effects.show](this.effects.duration, function(){
            $(this).show();
            $('.message span').show();
            $('.message').children().show();
        });

        if (this.autoHide)
        {   // Remove message after delay
            $('.message').data('objMessage', this);
            $('.message').delay(3000).queue(function(el){
                $(this).data('objMessage').close();
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Removes generated message from the screen
     * @method close
     * @public
     */
    close: function() {
        $('.message')[this.effects.hide](this.effects.duration, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You mean like `$(myElement).queue(function(el){});`? Cos that's possible...

Comment: What kind of object does `this` represent in your code?

Comment: @am not i am : it is the object literal. Code example which I gave you is in a method of this object

Comment: How are you using `.queue()`. That method just operates on whatever jQuery object it happened to be called from. Do you need this data associated with a particular element, or set of elements? If so, have you considered `$.data()`?

Comment: @am not i am  : I have edited my post to give you context.

Comment: So it seems that you're using `.data()`. Is that working correctly for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still access the current object. See my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9upJB/

Aside from that, what others have pointed out is correct. `live()` (which you should STOP using btw) is an event. `queue()` is a method and has nothing to do with an event.

When accessing the object, this is executed as the callback (check the jQuery documentation).

Answer (score 2):

> *"Is it possible ?"*

No. The `live()` method is an event handling method, and you're setting event object data. The first argument in the callback is the *event* object.

I don't know what `this` represented, but I have a feeling you were misusing event data.

The `queue()` method has nothing to do with event handling. You pass it a function that is added to a queue. Its first parameter will reference a function that releases the queue.

Answer (score 1):

you first save the instance as element data and use it in queue function of jquery;

```
$("#el").data("instance", this);
```

en after that use in the function

```
$("#el").queue(function(){
    var instance = $(this).data("instance");
    //do whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the `queue()` function the element instead the function is executed on the matched element.

```
$('yourelement').queue();
```